# how to identify project type of existing visual studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I identify the project type of an existing visual studio project?  I need to follow the implementation patterns that were put in place by a previous developer.  He created one solution as a class library. However, the following VS project types use the same icons:

- Class Library
- Class Library (Portable)
- Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)

Are all of these project types essentially the same but simply labeled differently? I looked in the sln and proj files and I didn't see a project type indicator.  I would have expected something like a constant or enumerated value in one of these files to indicate the project type. Does a project type indicator not exist in these files or did I simply overlook it?

Answer (score 4):

Edit the csjproj files as text file and find the value of the xml element with name ProjectTypeGuids. Then check the value against this list:
https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Comment: I did a recursive text search on the outer directory and no "ProjectTypeGuid" was found

Comment: Simply right click on it and choose Edit/Open with notepad. .csproj is xml in fact and you will be able to see its content and find ProjectTypeGuids

Comment: here's the full content of the csproj:  https://jsfiddle.net/r4gsj52q/1/.  no reference to ProjectTypeGuid

Comment: looks like this is a .net core project.  guessing that it doesn't follow the traditional pattern that you're describing